# Jmeter HLS plugin .ts content blank

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to develop HLS load test using jmeter and it's new HLS plugin.

When I add a View Results Tree listener, I can see the .m3u8 access with it's response data, but when I want to see .ts file response data is empty.

What does it mean? The test is running bad? I have to configure something more?

Thanks.

Comment: But, why does the test finish in about 15 seconds if I ask for 60 seconds of video content?

Comment: This is another question :-) . It's a limitation of current plugin, it does not simulate the playing of the video. While the one I pointed you at does, but it's not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**.ts**" files are binary and usually very big.

There is no benefit in storing/showing their content.

So this Free JMeter plugin you're using computes performance metrics for them and that’s all.

Note that if you’re interested in:

- metrics showing user experience (lags, play time...)
- more video streaming format
- realistic player simulation

You may have a look at this alternative commercial plugin:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/videostreaming-plugin-with-live-and-abr-streaming/

Disclaimer : we are providers of this JMeter plugin